# If $f(x) \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow a+ $ and $g(x) \geq 1$, $x \in \mathbb R $, then $\dfrac{g(x)}{f(x)} \rightarrow \infty$, $x\rightarrow a+$

Tags: real-analysis, limits-without-lhopital, epsilon-delta

This is true right?

My approach:

If $f(x) \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow a+ $ then $a < x < a+\delta \rightarrow |f(x)| < \epsilon$

$f(x) \leq |f(x)| < \epsilon \rightarrow \dfrac{1}{f(x)} > \dfrac{1}{\epsilon}$

Let $M = \dfrac{1}{\epsilon}$

Then,

$\dfrac{g(x)}{f(x)} \geq \dfrac{1}{f(x)} > \dfrac{1}{\epsilon} = M $

Thus,

$\dfrac{g(x)}{f(x)} > M $ whenever $a < x < a+\delta$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this only holds if $f(x)>0$.   If the function approaches 0 but bounces between positive and negative,  then your limit will not exist as it will oscillate between positive and negative larger and larger values.

Example:  $f(x)=x\cdot {\sin (\frac 1 x)} $,  $g(x)=2$,   $a=0$

Comment: Oh thank you so much. $f(x) \leq |f(x)| < \epsilon$ this is where I got wrong then

Comment: But does your $f(x) \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow 0+$ ?

Comment: woops, I need it to be times x, not divided by x for that,  fixing

Comment: Yeah now it's correct! :)

Comment: @Lucifer No problem, welcome to M.S.E.  If this answered your question (Which it seems to!)  Go ahead and mark it with a green check next to the answer,  it both helps show the system that the question has been answered and awards some rep.